# Command-line parameters in bash script not recognised

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I use Debian (Raspbian) Wheezy. If this command line works fine:

```
smsd -c sms/out -i 60 -0 -f sms/smsd.log
```

and this alias also works fine:

```
bsmsd='smsd -c sms/out -i 60 -0 -f sms/smsd.log'
```

then why does this self-same command line in an executable bash script start the command `smsd`, but does not see any of the parameters I'm specifying? This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

smsd -c sms/out -f /home/pi/sms/smsd.log -i 60 -0 -v
```

I've tried redirecting and piping, to no avail.

I'm invoking the script (it's called ssmsd) from the command line like so:

```
./ssmsd
```

After that, this is the output from `ps -fC smsd`:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

Edit: I know it doesn't recognise the parameters, because it tells me I didn't specify a spooling directory. But I *did*: `-c sms/out`. When called from the script, it gives version number and author, and exits.

Perhaps I should add: it [calls itself](http://linux.die.net/man/8/gnokii-smsd) a daemon, but it's not a [*well-behaved*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515165/correct-daemon-behaviour-from-pep-3143-explained) daemon. You can't `smsd start|stop|restart` it, and it doesn't run in the background. So if I call it from a command line (or with that alias) and then start another terminal and do `ps -fC smsd`, I get:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
pi        2860  2621  0 17:49 pts/0    00:00:00 smsd -c xxxxxxx -i 60 -0 -f sms/smsd.log
```

Comment: How are you invoking the script? What makes you think it doesn't see the parameters? What does `ps -fC smsd` give?

Comment: The parameters in the version that works (`-f sms/smsd.log'`) are not the same than in the version that fails (`-v`). Maybe is that what's causing the failure?

Answer (score 1):

This looks rather obvious, you're not using the same arguments.

If this is `gnokii-smsd` and you specify `-v`, just like you're specifying in the script version it should print version and exit, just like you told it does.

Why haven't you tried with the **exact** same arguments when in shell mode than in script mode?

Comment: (slaps forehead) Because the `-v` was in my blind spot. Thank You! You're right, removing it fixed it. The documentation doesn't say '-v option makes smsd ignore any other parameters'.

Comment: And it is indeed `gnokii-smsd`.